# How to use a semi circle inside a container like in this image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make semi circle like in image inside container i have tried a lot but couldn't figure out how to make this

[image]

Now let me explain what i have tried so far and how i got the result

I have tried using custompainter class but am getting result like this:

```
enum CircleAlignment {
  topLeft,
  topRight,
  bottomLeft,
  bottomRight,
}

class QuarterCirclePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final CircleAlignment circleAlignment;
  final Color color;

  const QuarterCirclePainter({this.circleAlignment, this.color});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final radius = math.min(size.height, size.width-80);
    final offset = circleAlignment == CircleAlignment.topLeft
        ? Offset(.0, .0)
        : circleAlignment == CircleAlignment.topRight
        ? Offset(size.width, 5)
        : circleAlignment == CircleAlignment.bottomLeft
        ? Offset(.0, size.height+10)
        : Offset(size.width, size.height);
    canvas.drawCircle(offset, radius, Paint()..color = color);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(QuarterCirclePainter oldDelegate) {
    return color == oldDelegate.color &&
        circleAlignment == oldDelegate.circleAlignment;
  }
}
```

But am getting result like this:

[image]

Anyone got idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of a text being at the centre of a circle.

You can just replace the text with your image, can also choose where you would like to align the child in your case the image widget

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 500,
      height: 250,
      color: Colors.pink,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(90)),
                border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.green, style: BorderStyle.solid)),
            child: Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('asdasd'))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have edited so that curve is only one side of the border now. on the top left as you expect

**Edit:**

Not ideal semi curve on top right, however close, I think you can play around with the radius values, and find what you want @M.Yogeshwaran

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return         Container(      
      width: 500,
      height:250,
      color: Colors.pink,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 1,
          child: Container(                    
                      width: 115,
                      height: 125,

                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.orange,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft:  Radius.circular(60), bottomRight:  Radius.circular(80), topRight:  Radius.circular(60)),
          border: Border.all(width: 3,color: Colors.green,style: BorderStyle.none)
          ),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('asdasd'))),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no no image is different which i can place in center what is need  is  that corner circle in container

Comment: thanks tolga i have tried the above code but is looks same exactly like the image i posted can you please look at the original image circle , this looks sharp

Answer (score 0):

Before using this, make sure if you using a "Stack Widget"

```
Positioned(
        top: -(displayWidth(context) * 0.085),
        left: -(displayWidth(context) * 0.15),
        child: Container(
          height: displayWidth(context) * 0.5,
          width: displayWidth(context) * 0.5,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: HexColor('a4d9e9'),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
              displayWidth(context) * 0.5
            ))
          ),
        ),
      ),
```